# Pedro Ramirez super power

Tags: bang

From the rules:

> during phase 1 of his turn, he may choose to draw the first card from
>   the top of the discard pile or from the deck.

Are the cards in the discard pile visible?

Doesn't this incentivize the previous player to put the worst one on top when throwing many cards in the discrad pile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the discard pile is face up. This is standard in almost any game, unless the rules specify otherwise. While the rulebook for Bang! doesn't seem to specifically state this either way, it does say that brown-bordered cards are

> played by putting them directly into the discard pile and applying the effect described with text ore symbols on the cards".

This wouldn't make sense if the discard pile were face-down, as you wouldn't see the card that was just played if that were the case.

And yes, if someone is discarding multiple cards at once, they could put the least helpful card on top to try and hurt Pedro Ramirez. However, it is not common that a player will actually be discarding many cards at once; most cards that go into the discard pile go there from being played. Only if you have exceeded your hand limit at the end of your turn would you be discarding more than 1 card at a time.

Comment: Multiple cards get discarded more often then you would think. Anytime a card/cards are played in response to something all of them will go to the discard at the same time and the order can be chosen. Also the cards that require a card to be discarded to play also end with both cards going to the discard pile at the same time. At least that is how my group always played.

Comment: @JoeW The rules state that when you play a brown-bordered card, you place it directly into the discard pile. So a Bang! card would already be in the discard pile before a Miss! card is played in response.

Comment: Strange I never remembered that from the rules but have always played with the mindset that until a card is fully resolved it can't be placed in the discard. This also eliminates confusion as to who responded to cards that hit every player or how many bangs have been played in response to a dual. To me it doesn't make sense to put something directly in the discard when every player on the table might need to respond to it.